# CSS: How to get height of element to stay at final animated height?

Tags: css

When I animate some properties like height below, once the animation is finished it snaps back to either a different height or no height.  I have tried setting `height: auto` so that I can stay at 100% but that didn't seem to do anything.  Not sure what I am missing so that the attribute's value is retained at the end of the animation.

```css
.parent {
    animation: expand 3s 1;
}

@keyframes expand {

   from {
     width: 0%;
     height: 0%;
   }

    to {
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;

    }

  }
```

```html
<div class="parent" style="background-color: red;">


 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`animation-fill-mode: forwards`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode). This will make the final values of the animation stay after the animation has ended.

In your case, just append `forwards` to the `animation` shorthand.

Comment: ah didn't know that property existed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to like this

```js
function AnimationListener(e) {     
    var clientHeight = e.target.clientHeight;
    var clientwidth= e.target.clientWidth;
  //  alert('height - '+clientHeight+'  width - '+clientwidth);
    console.log('height - '+clientHeight+'  width - '+clientwidth);
}

var anim = document.getElementById("parent");
anim.addEventListener("animationend", AnimationListener, false);
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
   html{
      height: 100%;
    }
    body{
      height: 100%;
    }
    .parent {
        animation: expand 3s 1 forwards;
    }

    @keyframes expand {

       from {
         width: 0%;
         height: 0%;
       }

        to {
          width: 50%;
          height: 100%;

        }

      }
    </style>
 </head>

<div class="parent" id="parent"  style="background-color: red;">
 
 </div>
```